# Why can't I run python -m scripts.retrain -h from the Tensorflow for Poets example?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm following the *[Tensorflow for Poets](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/index.html#3)* example to learn about image classification and I'm running into an error in the Terminal after running this command as instructed:

```
python -m scripts.retrain -h
```

The error I received is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/Users/qaneuro/poeticFlow/tensorflow-for-poets-2/scripts/retrain.py", line 109, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
```

I ran pwd to confirm I was in the downloaded folder for the tutorial and it correctly shows:

```
/Users/qaneuro/poeticFlow/tensorflow-for-poets-2
```

Everything seemed to be working fine up until this point.  Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be obvious, but you don't seem to have TensorFlow installed.

The instructions can be found here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/

For the non-optimised version, you can generally just run `pip install tensorflow` (but it wouldn't make use of the GPU or some of the CPU instructions)

Comment: I've done this installation successfully numerous times so this might be a stupid question but do I need to install Tensorflow every time I turn my computer off?  Also the Tensorflow for Poets example didn't explicitly say we should put the project inside the bin folder of our Tensorflow installation so I'm a bit confused.  What's your take?

Comment: You can run the Python interpreter, e.g. just `python` (without args) and run `import tensorflow as tf` to confirm that TensorFlow has actually installed successfully. I suspect it either hasn't. Or it has in a different environment. It's difficult to know without knowing how you installed TensorFlow.

Comment: Note: it refers to the TensorFlow setup on this page: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/index.html#1 ("Setup" section of the linked example)

Comment: Just to answer your question "Also the Tensorflow for Poets example didn't explicitly say we should put the project inside the bin folder of our Tensorflow installation" - no, the example and TensorFlow installation are separate. There may be confusion about what installing TensorFlow means. You can checkout the TensorFlow repo and build it from source. But to install it, it will have to end up in Python's packages (site-packages). I'd recommend just installing the Python package to start with (even if it is slower). You can optmise it later.